# Android: Google Maps API V2 - My Location button toggle icon/blue

Tags: android, google-maps

How can I make "My Location" button to be toggled Blue for tracking and following current location or simple/default grey for not following? 
It would be toggled by clicking, so when user clicks on "My Location" button in corner it would change into blue (same as google maps).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you enable the "My Location" layer with `setMyLocationEnabled(true)` you are unable to change the functionality of the location marker or the location button.  You won't be able to accomplish what you want by simply enabling the "My Location" layer.  You will need to simulate the functionality of the "My Location" layer by creating a similar button yourself and implementing the behavior that you described.